# lookup array value from one table into other and prepare map, key and value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to pyspark and looking for below result.

Table A which has list of only employee names

```
#+---------------------------+
#|   emp_names_list          |
#+---------------------------+
#|   [Sham,Kishor]           | 
#|   [Bob,Alex]              |
```

Table B is a separate table which has employee name and emp id's but all employee names and id's are not under single column, they are spread across multiple columns

```
#+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+
#| emp_name1 | emp_id_1 | emp_name2 |emp_id_2 |emp_name3 |emp_id_3|
#+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------------+--------+
#|  Sham     |  5       |  Alex     |   10    |Kishor    |  11    |
#|  Bob      |  7       |           |         |          |        |
```

output needed , I am looking for new column in table A i.e name_id_map
like below , note- you can see each key has some value that value need to be
fetch/lookup from Table B, example for the key **Sham** the value **5** is searched from Table B

```
#+-----------------------+----------------------+
#|  emp_names_list       | name_id_map          |   
#+-----------------------+-----+----------------+
#| [Sham,Kishor]         | [Sham:5,Kishor:11]   | 
#| [Bob,Alex]            | [Bob:7,Alex:10]      |
```

I have tried to explod list of emp_name_list in table A and join with each column of table B but no luck.

Comment: can you tell us about the cardinality ? what did you try ?

Comment: why don't you create the output directly from the table B ? why do you need to lookup ?

Comment: the output is required for all the column values against table A

Comment: can you update the question with better example? For now you can get the output you need with just TableB

Comment: @koiralo ,can you please check now

Comment: it is possible to `broadcast` one of the two tables? How many records has each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following and let me know if it works for you.

The following assumes that you have created a temporary view or that you have access to the tables/views of `table_a` and `table_b` in your spark session. This can be achieved by

```py
table_a_df.createOrReplaceTemporaryView('table_a')
table_b_df.createOrReplaceTemporaryView('table_b')
```

if there are dataframes.

You may then run the following examples using spark sql on your spark session. eg

```py
result_df = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql statement from below here>")
```

Since I do not have your set up, i'm using CTEs to create a reproducible example in `table_b` and `table_a`. However, I've included the sql without these CTEs at the end of this answer also.

I assumed `emp_name_list` in `table_a` was an array. I started by simplifying `table_b` to a `name` and `id` column with the `emp_data` CTE, I then matched that using a join on `table_a` using `array_contains` and extracted the `emp_name_list` along with the `name` and `id` matched in `emp_matches`.

The final select groups by `emp_name_list` and uses `collect_list` to aggregate the name-id pairs into an array.

```sql
      WITH table_b AS (
          SELECT 
              'Sham' as emp_name1, 
              5 as emp_id_1,
              'Alex' as emp_name2,
              10 as emp_id_2,
              'Kishor' as emp_name3,
              11 as emp_id_3
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 
              'Bob' as emp_name1, 
              7 as emp_id_1,
              NULL as emp_name2,
              NULL as emp_id_2,
              NULL as emp_name3,
              NULL as emp_id_3
      ),
      table_a AS (
          SELECT SPLIT(emp_names_list,',') as emp_names_list FROM (
              SELECT 'Sham,Kishor' as emp_names_list UNION ALL 
              SELECT 'Bob,Alex' as emp_names_list
          ) t
      ),
      emp_data AS (
          SELECT  e1.id, e1.name FROM (
          SELECT emp_name1 as name, emp_id_1 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name2 as name, emp_id_2 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name3 as name, emp_id_3 as id FROM table_b 
          ) e1
          WHERE e1.name is not null or e1.id is not null
      ),
      emp_matches AS (
          SELECT DISTINCT
              a1.emp_names_list, 
              CONCAT(e1.name,':',e1.id) as name_id 
          FROM 
              emp_data e1
          INNER JOIN
              table_a a1 ON array_contains(a1.emp_names_list,e1.name)
      )
      SELECT
          emp_names_list,
          collect_list(name_id) name_id_map
      FROM 
          emp_matches
      GROUP BY
          emp_names_list
```

or try the following if `name_id_map` is of data type map. The query below is similar to the one above except it uses additional functions to have the final `name_id_map` as a map.

```sql
      WITH table_b AS (
          SELECT 
              'Sham' as emp_name1, 
              5 as emp_id_1,
              'Alex' as emp_name2,
              10 as emp_id_2,
              'Kishor' as emp_name3,
              11 as emp_id_3
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 
              'Bob' as emp_name1, 
              7 as emp_id_1,
              NULL as emp_name2,
              NULL as emp_id_2,
              NULL as emp_name3,
              NULL as emp_id_3
      ),
      table_a AS (
          SELECT SPLIT(emp_names_list,',') as emp_names_list FROM (
              SELECT 'Sham,Kishor' as emp_names_list UNION ALL 
              SELECT 'Bob,Alex' as emp_names_list
          ) t
      ),
      emp_data AS (
          SELECT  e1.id, e1.name FROM (
          SELECT emp_name1 as name, emp_id_1 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name2 as name, emp_id_2 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name3 as name, emp_id_3 as id FROM table_b 
          ) e1
          WHERE e1.name is not null or e1.id is not null
      ),
      emp_matches AS (
          SELECT DISTINCT
              a1.emp_names_list, 
              CONCAT(e1.name,':',e1.id) as name_id 
          FROM 
              emp_data e1
          INNER JOIN
              table_a a1 ON array_contains(a1.emp_names_list,e1.name)
      )
      SELECT
          emp_names_list,
          str_to_map(concat_ws(';',collect_list(name_id)),',',';') name_id_map
      FROM 
          emp_matches
      GROUP BY
          emp_names_list
```

actual spark sql without table_b and table_a references

```sql
      WITH emp_data AS (
          SELECT  e1.id, e1.name FROM (
          SELECT emp_name1 as name, emp_id_1 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name2 as name, emp_id_2 as id FROM table_b UNION ALL
          SELECT emp_name3 as name, emp_id_3 as id FROM table_b 
          ) e1
          WHERE e1.name is not null or e1.id is not null
      ),
      emp_matches AS (
          SELECT DISTINCT
              a1.emp_names_list, 
              CONCAT(e1.name,':',e1.id) as name_id 
          FROM 
              emp_data e1
          INNER JOIN
              table_a a1 ON array_contains(a1.emp_names_list,e1.name)
      )
      SELECT
          emp_names_list,
          str_to_map(concat_ws(';',collect_list(name_id)),';',',') name_id_map
      FROM 
          emp_matches
      GROUP BY
          emp_names_list
```

You may need to enable the option on your [spark config](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true`

Comment: this solution work but I have to use spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true before joining emp_data and table_a i.e while executing code in emp_matches AS() block

Comment: @punm I've updated the answer shared to suggest this also